# Select on row in left with one to many relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table obs

```
+--------+-------+
| obs_id | name  |
+--------+-------|
| 101    | mics  |
| 102    | jan   |
+--------+-------+
```

I have table monitoring

```
+--------+--------+---------+
| mon_id | obs_id | code_id |
+--------+--------+---------+
|   1    |  101   | 201     |
|   2    |  101   | 201     |
|   3    |  101   | 202     |
|   4    |  102   | 201     |
|   5    |  102   | 202     |
+--------+--------+---------+
```

I have table code

```
+--------+-----------+
|code_id | code_name |
+--------+-----------|
| 201    |  node     |
| 202    |  java     |
| 203    |  c++      |
+--------+-----------+
```

Query result

```
+--------+--------+---------+-----------+
| obs_id | name   | code_id | code_name |
+--------+--------+---------+-----------+
|   101  |  mics  |  201    | node      |
|   102  |  jan   |  201    | node      |
+--------+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Can someone give me a proper mysql query to come up my result.

```
select A.obs_id, A.name, M.code_id, C.code_name from obs as A  
left join monitoring as M on M.obs_id = A.obs_id
left join code as C on C.code_id = M.code_id
```

The return of my query is more than 2 or it is not what I want as a result.

Comment: Why are you ignoring the java codes?

Comment: Note that mon_id is redundant in this context. You have a perfectly serviceable natural key on (obs_id,code_id) meaning the surrogate is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

As per your result ,its look like you want to results for only 'node' .
Then query will be look like below :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GETDATA

AS

@CodeId int=0

BEGIN

select DISTINCT A.obs_id, A.name, M.code_id, C.code_name from obs as A  

left join monitoring as M on M.obs_id = A.obs_id

left join code as C on C.code_id = M.code_id WHERE c.code_id=@CodeId

END
```

Now ,you need to only pass codeID into stored Procedure  ,it will be return an output based on CodeID . Its look like dynamic .

The above query will give result as you required.

If you want to get distinct data for all code, then just remove where condition.

Thanks .

Comment: no sir. it will not only return code_name node. it is dynamic it defends of what code id is use .

Comment: Hi , Mics you can use stored procedure for dynamic behavior .Please check my answer .

Comment: i didnt use stored procedure in my other query .